# call to shallow nested path: post_up_vote_path(post), fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

Earlier, to make path calls easier, I changed my routes.rb file to implement shallow nesting in the following manner:

```
SampleApp::Application.routes.draw do

  get "comments/create"
  devise_for :users
  resources :users, only: [:update]

  resources :topics do
    resources :posts, except: [:index]
  end

  resources :posts, only: [] do
    resources :comments, only: [:create, :destroy]
  end

  post '/up-vote' => 'votes#up_vote', as: :up_vote
  post '/down-vote' => 'votes#down_vote', as: :down_vote
  get 'about' => 'welcome#about'

  root to: 'welcome#index'
end
```

Yet, when i call post_up_vote_path(post) within a partial, it fails to recognize the path method:

```
<div class='vote-arrows'>
  <div class='pull-left'>
    <div><%= link_to " ", post_up_vote_path(post), class: 'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up', method: :post %></div>
    <div><strong><%= post.points %></strong></div>
    <div><%= link_to " ", post_down_vote_path(post), class: 'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down', method: :post %></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I call the above partial (_vote.html.erb) within a show view:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <%= render partial: 'votes/voter', locals: {post: @post} %>
    ...
```

Is there something from this code that shows that there is an error?

Answer (score 0):

Your routes are incorrect - you're naming them as `down_vote` and `up_vote`, not `post_down_vote` and `post_up_vote`.

If you check the output of `rake routes`, it will tell you what names you should be using.